# How to divide a vector in R so that the sum of the chunks is the same

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am trying to optimize some R code to compute the euclidean distance in a very big matrix (bigger than what dist allows). In order to speed up the process I am sending which column of the matrix to calculate colSums against the matrix using doParallel.
However this is inefficient when parallelizing given the last columns of the matrix is very small. So I am trying to optimize the code by dividing the calculation into segments of roughly the same number of computation. Ideally I would divide this so that the sum of a vector from 1 to nCols has the same sum, but this is a NP complex problem from what I can gather. Is there any other way of getting a similar results?

My code is below:

```
library(doParallel)

ncores <- 140
cl<-makeCluster(ncores)
registerDoParallel(cl)

#number of samples
samples <- 10000
#number of markers
markers <- 160000

#input markers matrix
A <- matrix(1:5, ncol=samples,nrow=markers, byrow=T)
btime <- system.time(
  bresult<-foreach(x=1:(ncol(A)-1),.combine="c",.multicombine=T,.inorder=T) %dopar% {
      colSums(as.matrix(A[,x]-A[,(x+1):ncol(A)])^2,na.rm = T)
  }
)
```

Comment: [you can use my code](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation/blob/master/src/dist_calcs.cpp)

Comment: Which code Alex?

Comment: The above link. You may want [this one](https://github.com/alexWhitworth/imputation/blob/master/R/int-impute_fn_knn.R) too, idk